# Server socket reading its output before client input. Socket reading/writing ordering?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, serversocket, outputstream

I have a client-server model set up using one socket with two way communication.

It supposed to go like this:
1. Client - send array of words
2. Server - read array of words
3. Server - send boolean 
4. Client - read boolean
5. Client - send image
6. Server - read image

this process is within a loop and works perfectly with the first iteration, though with the second iteration I get the following error:

Java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

What I think is happening is that when the server gos back to reading the array of words (#2) its reading in the boolean it previously sent (#3), or the image that the the client has previously sent (#5).  If this is the case does anyone know of a solution to this problem?  I was thinking perhaps using two sockets could fix this problem, but then again I wouldn't know how to implement it using two sockets! Im sort of a newbie!

I have labelled the order of execution in the program below.

Client

```
  private void whileConnected() throws IOException{ 
        do{                                 
                analyser.start();
                boolean takeScreenShot = false;

                if(analyser.isCaptured)
                {
                    **output.writeObject(analyser.getCapturedText()); // 1**
                    output.flush();

                    **takeScreenShot = input.readBoolean(); //4**

                    if(takeScreenShot == true);
                    {
                        ScreenShot ss = new ScreenShot();
                        BufferedImage screenShot = ss.getScreenShot();
                        if(screenShot != null)
                        {
                            **ImageIO.write(screenShot, "png",output); // 5**
                            output.flush();
                        }

                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }while(true);   
    }
```

Server

```
private void whileConnected() throws IOException {
    do {
        try {

            analyserDetail = new AnalyserDetail();

            **analyserDetail.text = (String[]) input.readObject(); // 2** 


            if(analyserDetail.text != null)
            {
                analyserDetail.username = "Michael";
                analyserDetail.positionFound = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                analyserDetail.wordsFound = new ArrayList<String>();
                analyserDetail.wordCount = 0;

                findProfanity();

                if(analyserDetail.wordCount > 0)
                {
                    new CreateReport(analyserDetail);
                    //output.writeObject(new Boolean(true));
                    **output.writeBoolean(true); // 3**
                    output.flush();
                    output.reset();
                   **BufferedImage screenShot = ImageIO.read(input); //6**

                   if(screenShot != null)
                   {
                    java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        String reportName = formatter.format(today);
                        new StoreScreenShot(screenShot,reportName);
                   }
                }else
                {
                    output.writeObject("False");
                    output.flush();
                }

            }

            analyserDetail = null;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("\nI dont know wtf was sent!");
        }
    } while (true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
output.writeObject("False");
```

should almost certainly be

```
output.writeBoolean(false);
```

Comment: cheers though this isnt the problem, the first iteration of my loop everything reads in which its supposed to.  Its crashing when the server trys to read in the  **analyserDetail.text = (String[]) input.readObject(); // 2** .. i think its reading in either the boolean value from **output.writeBoolean(true); // 3** or the image from   **ImageIO.write(screenShot, "png",output); // 5**, and is crashing because its trying to cast either of the previous two to (String[])